# How to auto update a running docker container on a new merge

Tags: git, docker, github, dockerfile

Okay guys,

so I have the following scenario. I am currently working on a little flask web app. The code for this project including the docker file is stored inside GitHub.

What I am doing in the moment, is that with every new release I manually stop and delete the old docker container, clone the new repository and manually create a new build which I start up.

However, I am absolutely sure that there has to be a way to automatically update the running docker container with a new release. I think it an be achieved with GitHub Actions. Unfortunately I've never worked with them before and I am also really new in the Docker/Github game.

Maybe some of you can give me a little input on how possible ways to automate the whole process. I am thankful for every little hint. I don't expect for anyone to completely solve it for me. Hoverer I am alway grateful for examples (even dummy examples).

Comment: Where are you hosting it?

Comment: Personally I prefer to use kubernetes for managing deployments and orchestrating containers. It's great for no-downtime deployments, restarting the container if it crashes, scaling, etc. But it might be overkill for your use-case. And managed kubernetes can be a bit costly. Anyways, would help to know if you need to host it on some VM or if you use some cloud provider service or similar.

Comment: I am hosting it on my own VM atm.